# How to pass two different type of param in mockito

Tags: java, json, mockito

I am doing really simply thing but facing some issue. 
So wrote one really simple method which take one JsonObject and on the basis of key it extract JsonArry. 
Its working fine but when I am trying to write Unit test then facing issue. 
So following is method that need to test.

```
public String getA(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    JSONArray educationsArray = jsonService.getJsonArray(jsonObject, "a");
}

public String getB(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    JSONArray educationsArray = jsonService.getJsonArray(jsonObject, "b");
}
```

here is the unit test that I am trying to write.

```
String json = fileUtil.readFile("data.json");
String content = (String) new JSONObject(json).get("data");
JSONObject contentJson = new JSONObject(content);
when(jsonLinkExtractorService.getJsonArray(contentJson, "a")).thenReturn(jsonArray);
```

it read json file for data , extract data type of element which again json payload and then finally create new JSONObject with extracted String. After doing all this did simple mocking with newly created json object and passed the key.

not when actually method is called then it return null. Probably reason is object JsonObject are different for Mockito that's why not able to match. 
When I changed these two param to any(), any() then it work find but then it did not filter as per key. 
So could someone help me either somehow Mockito can match two newly created object or can I mock like following statement.

```
any(), "a"
```

I tried but it throws exception. 
Can someone help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ArgumentMatchers` for one the parameters, you have to use it for all of them. In this case, use `ArgumentMatchers.eq("a")` instead of `"a"`:

```
when(jsonLinkExtractorService.getJsonArray(any(), eq("a"))).thenReturn(jsonArray);
```